# Search Api Solr - Pointing term links inside a view to its facet

Tags: 7, views, search

Using [Search Api](http://www.drupal.org/project/search_api). Solr as a backened. Search pages built with Views. When adding a term field to a view, that term links to the core taxonomy term pages. That term should instead link to it's facet(not adding to the other facets if the user had previously click on other facets).

I have searched high and wide for any documentation or discussion involving this, and only found a few issues that didn't go anywhere. There is hardly any discussion, which I find odd because I would imagine this would be a pretty common request.

Does anyone have any knowledge on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want the fields in the search results to have taxonomy terms that are linked to the facet URL instead of the taxonomy page of the item? It just seems a little redundant, because that's what the facets there are for.

A solution would be to use FacetAPI Pretty Paths and rewrite the output link of the taxonomy term to match the URL of the facet. You'll need the fields term name and id, then format as : www.example.com/search-page/[pretty paths term]/[term name]-[term id]

Comment: Say a user searches for something, then filters by Network, then by tv show.  The view row displays the main stars that are on the show(which are terms).  The user looks at the view results and sees the name of his favorite actor, and says, "I want to see everything that he is in." He clicks on it, and now the view reset all the filters and shows results of everything that actor is in, as if the user just clicked on that actors filter facet.  I have already tried the solution with pretty paths, and once you do that, your facet links point to term pages.  It doesnt work

Comment: For this, you need to use the base URL as the search page, then that activates the facet based on the URL. For example, if the URL of your search page is www.example.com/search, you need to rewrite the taxonomy link to be search/[pretty paths term]/[term name]-[term id], then it will activate just that facet.